# Makefile Awk using $ for column gets syntax error, while it works fine on console

Tags: awk, makefile, syntax-error

I'm using the below line perfectly fine on the console, but when i use it in a makefile i get the below error. I have tried different things for last hour, nothing helps me. Also i have to use  '@' before the command in makefile, that is normal only. Any help is greatly welcome.

Command on console

```
cpio -itv < rootfs.cpio | awk '!/^d/{$8="";print}' | sort -k8 > rootfs.layout.trim
```

Error

```
awk: !/^d/{="";print}
awk:       ^ syntax error
```

In makefile

```
log-rootfs:
# copy the layout dump with all the modification needed to sync with stb output
# get the file list from cpio file => remove the lines with directory name => sort the output and store the same in layout file
cpio -itv < $(ROOTFS_CPIO_FILE) | awk '!/^d/{$8="";print}' | sort -k8 > $(ROOTFS_LAYOUT)
@echo $(ROOTFS_LAYOUT) is created
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`make` is looking for a variable/macro named `$8`.  In general, `$` needs to be escaped in the makefile, and if you want to pass a literal `$` to the shell, you should use `$$` in the makefile.  In other words, try:

```
rule:
  ... awk '!/^d/{$$8="";print}' ...
```